# Is it possible to make nodejs execute some code after it has been launched

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to make nodejs execute some code after it has been launched.

After Node.js started, I hope it can loads some code interprets and executes them.

Is there any module can do this?

Your comment welcome

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? We have different tools for executing code. What kind of code? Is it Javascript? And then what do you want to do with the result? Is the code dynamic? Is it generated in runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a look at the [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) in the Node API, specifically [exec](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) for an easy example of executing a command from within Node.

Copied from the API doc:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```